# How can I search a specific node in this treeview from text input on a button press?

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a simple code for creating a tree structure with add, remove and edit buttons. I want to search a specific node from the added nodes via the text box(textBox1) and a button press(button4) but I just can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(textBox1.Text);



        try
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;    
    }

    private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();       
    }

    private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use linq query like this :

`TreeNode[] treeNodes = treeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>() .Where(r => r.Text == textBox1.Text).ToArray();`